# Print directly/silently to printer using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, printing, cordova-plugins

I was wondering if it's possible to print a PDF or raw text to printer on the network without asking which printer to take (so the printer is hardcoded).

I was checking some Cordova printer plugins and came up with this https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer but it's only for iOS.

Is it even possible? If so, how to do it?

Comment: AFAIK, Android's printing framework does not support this.

Comment: I raw printed "Hello World!" using socket connection via port 9100 (I sent basic TCP packet with "Hello World!" text). Now, how do I print PDF and images hmm...